# Grouping Totals With SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the situation:

I have a table that has two data columns:

```
Number | Value
     0 |    11
     0 |    10
     0 |    12
     1 |    10
     1 |    10
     1 |    11
     2 |    11
       .
       .
       .
```

And so on...

I would like to create a query that presents the totals for the different numbers separately, so it would end up being like so:

```
Number | Total
     0 |    33
     1 |    31
     2 |    11
       .
       .
       .
```

I've tried applying a simple SUM(Value) into my Query, but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a `group by` query.  It is a fundamental part of the SQL language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select number , sum(value) as "total" from tablename
group by Number
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This worked well! I guess I just didn't know enough about SQL to know what I was trying to do.

Comment: Use `sum(value)` instead of `sum(total)` ;).